# Update Lucene.net Indexes Regularly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lucene.net

I have an MVC site uses Lucene.net for its searching capabilities.  The site has over 100k products.  The indexes are built already for the site.  The site, however, also has 2 data feeds that update the database on a regular basis ( potentially every 15 mins ).  So the data is changing a lot.  How should I go about updating the Lucene indexes or do I not have to at all?

Comment: Are you saying the index is built once and never write to again? In this scenario I would definitely create a process to keep it up to date with the database.

Comment: Is there a way to write them the index again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a process scheduler (like [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net)) to run every so often (potentially, every 15 minutes) to fetch the items in the database that aren't indexed.

Use a field as an ID to compare against (like a sequence number or a date time). You would fetch the latest added document from the index and the latest from the database and index everything in between. You have to be careful not to index duplicates (or worse, skip over un-indexed documents).

Alternatively, synchronize your indexing with the 2 data feeds and index the documents as they are stored in the database, saving you from the pitfalls above (duplicates/missing). I'm unsure how these feeds are updating your database, but you can intercept them and update the index accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution, I had the same requirement and I used the solution from this link and it worked for me. Using a timer it creates the index every so often so there wont be any overlap/skipping issue. Give it a try.

[Making Lucene.Net thread safe in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813610/making-lucene-net-thread-safe-in-the-code)

Thanks.