# Making Lucene.Net thread safe in the code

Tags: c#, multithreading, search, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.Net for Searching and wanted to know how I can handle this threading issue.

I have a single instance of class Test, but the searcher is not threadsafe in this case, since the timer thread can update the index at the same time the request is served, and I do see exception due to that. Any pointers on how to make it thread safe.

```
public class Test 
{
    private static object syncObj = new object();

    private System.Threading.Timer timer;

    private Searcher searcher;

    private RAMDirectory idx = new RAMDirectory();

    public Test()
    {
        this.timer = new System.Threading.Timer(this.Timer_Elapsed, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
    }


    private Searcher ESearcher
    {
        get
        {
            return this.searcher;
        }

        set
        {
            lock (syncObj)
            {
                this.searcher = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Document CreateDocument(string title, string content)
    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.Add(new Field("A", title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
        doc.Add(new Field("B", content, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        return doc;
    }

    public List<Document> Search(Searcher searcher, string queryString)
    {
        List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "B", new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        Query query = parser.Parse(queryString);
        int hitsPerPage = 5;
        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(2 * hitsPerPage, true);
        this.ESearcher.Search(query, collector);

        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;

        int hitCount = collector.TotalHits > 10 ? 10 : collector.TotalHits;
        for (int i = 0; i < hitCount; i++)
        {
            ScoreDoc scoreDoc = hits[i];
            int docId = scoreDoc.Doc;
            float docScore = scoreDoc.Score;
            Document doc = searcher.Doc(docId);
            documents.Add(doc);
        }

        return documents;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender)
    {
        this.Log("Started Updating the Search Indexing");
        // Get New data to Index
        using (IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(this.idx, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED))
        {
            foreach (var e in es)
            {
                writer.AddDocument(this.CreateDocument(e.Value.ToString(), e.Key));
            }

            writer.Optimize();
        }

        this.ESearcher = new IndexSearcher(this.idx);
        this.Log("Completed Updating the Search Indexing");
    }

    public Result ServeRequest()
    {
        var documents = this.Search(this.EntitySearcher, searchTerm);
        //somelogic
        return result;

    }
```

}

Comment: Why are you using a single instance to start with?

Comment: In the timer_elapsed, switch off the timer, do the work, switch the timer back on again

Comment: @CodeCaster ServiceFabric will cache the instance, so it will reuse the same index.  Also whats the point of creating index everytime for new request.

Comment: Alright let me clarify: what part of this code exactly is not thread-safe? I suspected the `ESearcher` where you appear to be reusing a `Searcher` instance.

Comment: @CodeCaster The timerThread is setting the searcher ( this.searcher = value;)  and the Request Serving method ( public Result ServeRequest()) is using the this.ESearcher to search.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd that will only solve the issue during the Initialization, which I have done. But how about the subsequent timer updates.

Comment: @loneshark99 - no, if you add that code to the start of the method it will run on every invocation.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I can't switch off the timer, since the list on which its indexing will update every so often and i need to take those updates,

Comment: If that is true the design is wrong and there already is a race condition

Comment: I doubt that  , it's the right design

Comment: Could you explain why Timer_Elapsed is not locking on the sync object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lots of things "wrong" with this.

As has been mentioned the locking wasn't safe (you need to lock reads as well as writes).

More significantly, there are better ways of handling this in Lucene. First, `IndexWriter` is itself threadsafe. It should be the owner of the `Directory`. It's generally "bad practice" to have different parts opening/closing the directory.

There is a style for NRT (Near Real Time) indexes which involves getting an `IndexReader` from the IW, rather than wrapping the Directory.

The style used in your example is only really "good" if the index is essentially read-only and maybe regenerated in batch daily/weekly etc.

I have rewritten the example to show some of the approach. Obviously, as this is just test code there will be nuances that will need refactoring/enhancing depending on the use case...

```
public class Test
{
    private static object syncObj = new object();

    private System.Threading.Timer timer;

    private Searcher searcher;

    private IndexWriter writer;
    private IndexReader reader;

    public Test()
    {
        writer = new IndexWriter(new RAMDirectory(), new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
        reader = writer.GetReader();
        searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Timer_Elapsed, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
    }


    public void CreateDocument(string title, string content)
    {
        var doc = new Document();
        doc.Add(new Field("A", title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
        doc.Add(new Field("B", content, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        writer.AddDocument(doc);
    }

    public void ReplaceAll(Dictionary<string, string> es)
    {
        // pause timer
        timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

        writer.DeleteAll();
        foreach (var e in es)
        {
            AddDocument(e.Value.ToString(), e.Key);
        }

        // restart timer
        timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
    }

    public List<Document> Search(string queryString)
    {
        var documents = new List<Document>();
        var parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "B", new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        Query query = parser.Parse(queryString);
        int hitsPerPage = 5;
        var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(2 * hitsPerPage, true);
        searcher.Search(query, collector);

        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;

        int hitCount = collector.TotalHits > 10 ? 10 : collector.TotalHits;
        for (int i = 0; i < hitCount; i++)
        {
            ScoreDoc scoreDoc = hits[i];
            int docId = scoreDoc.Doc;
            float docScore = scoreDoc.Score;
            Document doc = searcher.Doc(docId);
            documents.Add(doc);
        }

        return documents;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender)
    {
        if (reader.IsCurrent())
            return;

        reader = writer.GetReader();
        var newSearcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref searcher, newSearcher);
        Debug.WriteLine("Searcher updated");
    }

    public Result ServeRequest(string searchTerm)
    {
        var documents = Search(searchTerm);
        //somelogic
        var result = new Result();

        return result;

    }
}
```

Note:

- the writer "owns" the directory
- if this was a file base Directory then you would have `Open` and `Close` methods to create/dispose the writer (which deals with handling the `lock` file). RamDirectory can just be GC'd
- uses `Interlocked.Exchange` instead of `lock`. So zero cost when using the `searcher` member (here be dragons!)
- new docs added directly to the writer
- `IsCurrent()` allows for zero cost if no new docs have been added. Depending on how frequently you are adding docs, you may not need the timer at all (just call `Timer_Elapsed` - renamed obviously - at the top of `Search`).
- don't use `Optimize()` it's a hangover from previous versions and it's use is highly discouraged (perf and disk I/O reasons)

Lastly, if you're using Lucene.net v4.8 then you should use `SearcherManager` (as suggested in another answer). But use the ctor that takes the `IndexWriter` and keep it as a "singleton" (same scope as `writer`). It will handle locking and getting new readers for you.

Comment: Take my upvote - respect for the amount of time and effort taken here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , few questions .where is the create document called , how is it created and updated. Iscurrent , how would it know about new data to be indexed .

Comment: @AndyPook  how to create the index because in ur code I don't see the call to create document  which is needed since that's the data that gets indexed

Comment: It wasn't clear from the example where the `es` collection came from. My version assumes that instead of adding to the `es` collection, you just call `CreateDocument` directly, which creates the doc and adds it to the index via the writer. My version keeps the index in memory rather than recreating it each time, which could be expensive if the collection is big. (ie treat it like a database). The idea was to isolate the index management parts away from other concerns. So, maybe a `Delete` method is needed. Obviously this is just an example you'll need to modify a bit to make it fit your needs

Comment: I've added a `ReplaceAll` method which some external "client" could call to replace the entire content of the index. NOTE that this is another area that your version is not threadsafe. `es` looks like a dictionary (?) which is not threadsafe ie it'll bork if you add an entry while the `foreach` is running

Comment: @AndyPook I will give it a try today and let you know. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using new IndexSearcher. You can use 'SearcherManager' class.

> SearcherManager _searcherManager = new
>   SearcherManager(LuceneMapDirectory, null);

And, search as follow:

```
_searcherManager.ExecuteSearch(searcher =>
        {
          //Execute query using <searcher>
        }, ex => { Trace.WriteLine(ex); });
```

Comment: you should note that SearcherManager is only available in v4.8

Comment: It doesn't seem like Lucene.net 4.8 has SearcherManager.ExecuteSearch anymore. I'm using the May 10th release